# Is Font Boosting Good UX?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, mobile-web, text

I begin with a quote from developer [John Mellor](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84186), which explains the mobile Chrome feature I'm talking about better than I can, and comes from the perspective of someone close to the feature.

> When viewing desktop websites on mobile devices, browsers usually
>   layout the page at a fixed width of about 980 CSS pixels due to the
>   default viewport settings. The user usually can't read the text when
>   the page is initially displayed, but can zoom in to read it. However
>   on a portrait phone screen, once zoomed in such that text is a legible
>   size, only about a 320 CSS pixel wide area of content fits onscreen at
>   a time.
>
> For wide columns of text, this means you'd either need to zoom out and
>   look at tiny unreadable / barely readable text, or you'd need to pan
>   left and right for every line of text you read. The same thing happens
>   (though less severely) on landscape phones and on portrait tablets.
>
> To prevent such situations, this bug tracks adding support for Font
>   Boosting (upstreamed from Chrome for Android). When pages load, Font
>   Boosting increases the font size of text in wide columns, so you won't
>   have to zoom in on them as much and hence every column fits onscreen
>   at a legible text size.

Firefox has apparently added similar features to its mobile browser, and called it Font Inflation. Personally I find it invasive in that it makes webpages look worse and there's no way to turn it off.

The question is: is this good UX? If not, can it be made good? If not, why is it bad?

Comment: Webdesigners can turn it off by setting a max-height to the containers. I agree with you that it makes a lot of websites look worse and I know at least two websites that aren't really usable anymore because the menu and login forms don't scale up, too. Either webdesigners care about responsibility, then font boosting normally is not needed, or they don't care and then it sometimes helps the reader but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Would the downvoter mind explaining what was bad about my question so I can improve it?

Comment: Right now this is a broad question as you aren't providing a context.  it's like asking "are checkboxes good UX?".  Overall I like the idea behind the question though, so please edit it to give more context and one of the mods can then reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

Web designers can accommodate for font boosting by using [relative CSS units](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/). So instead of setting a button's height as 20 pixels, you set it as twice the height of the font. That way the relevant parts of your UI will scale when font size changes.

However, many websites don't bother, as responsive design is more complex and the number of users with old phones and accessibility issues is small.

Because font boosting makes some websites better and others worse it's hard to say if it's good or bad UX.  For sure the inability to disable the function is annoying - a better approach might be to enable the feature as a sensible default, and include an option to disable it tucked away in advanced settings.

Answer (score 0):

If the site isn't designed so that I can read the text on my mobile browser, the mobile browser increasing the text size for me seems like good UX to me.

This is, ultimately, a workaround for poorly designed web sites that aren't set up to be responsive.

Comment: Even if it can make pages harder to read instead of easier?

Comment: @SamuelYusim the assumption is that the page isn't readable to begin with, hence the change in font size. Again, it's a workaround. Workarounds aren't foolproof. It's an attempt at fixing a poor UX in the first place. Hopefully most of the time it makes it better rather than worse.